# How to get the filesystem path to a JavaScript file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I use Rails 4. I can use URL helpers in my views to reference assets without thinking where the resources are located in the filesystem.

Is it easy to find location in the filesystem by providing only the asset name? I suppose that it should be possible as Rails do it somehow when serving assets.

For instance, if I use some gem and it has assets I'd like to have such a function:

```
f("chartkick.js") # => "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/chartkick-1.3.2/app/assets/javascripts/chartkick.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

It was simple. Just went thru asset paths and checked the first existing file:

`Rails.application.config.assets.paths.map {|x| x.to_s + "/chartkick.js" }.find { |x| File.exists?(x) }`